# texlive+pdflatex fontawesome.sty not found

Tags: apt, package-management, latex

I installed `texlive` with:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

and I use `pdflatex` that I think is shipped by `texlive`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
```

I am trying to use the `fontawesome` package, which [is supposed to be contained in `texlive`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome).

However, when I try to compile a `tex` document using `fontawesome`, it says

```
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome
```

What could be the problem? Interestingly, `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/` doesn't contain `fontawesome.sty` anywhere. I even tried

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

but it says all packages already exist.

Comment: It appears to be in [texlive-fonts-extra](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/texlive-fonts-extra) rather than texlive-latex-extra

Comment: @steeldriver that worked -- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install all the texlive packages with `sudo apt install texlive-full`, and never worry about missing packages again